# how do i import and use WordNet 3.0 in python?

Tags: python, wordnet

I have downloaded the latest version of WordNet 3.0. I am not able to find a proper documentation of how to use it in python.

Does NLTK have wordnet 3.0 ?

I have already used an older version of wordnet in nltk.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

No, it seems that NLTK only supports 3.0.

If I were doing this, I'd choose between using the 3.0 Java API through [Jython](http://www.jython.org) or spawn the `wn` executable using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

I'd lean towards the latter method in case I needed to integrate with an extensive existing codebase. Unfortunately this means doing work that a future 3.0 implementation in NLTK will make obsolete, but well - that's life.